# Variable `times` not defined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write code where a query is executed three times and the average execution time is displayed.

The error is:

```
Variable `times` not defined (line 14, column 6 (offset: 257))
"WITH times, i, end_time - start_time AS execution_time"
```

Can you help me please :)

Here's the code:

```
WITH []
AS times

UNWIND range(1,3) AS i
WITH times, i

WITH apoc.date.currentTimestamp() AS start_time

MATCH (a:Article)
WHERE a.appearsInJournal = "Journal of Science"
RETURN a.title, a.publicationDate

WITH apoc.date.currentTimestamp() AS end_time
WITH times, i, end_time - start_time AS execution_time
SET times = times + execution_time

WITH times, avg(times) AS avg_time

RETURN toFloat(avg_time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

*A `WITH` clause will drop all existing variables, except for the ones that are specified in the `WITH` clause.* Not all your `WITH` clauses are specifying `times`. That explains your error message.

But your main question is about how to use Cypher to determine the average execution time for a Cypher query.

Here is one approach. It executes your `query` 5 times and returns the average execution time in milliseconds, ignoring the timing of the first execution (with is generally more expensive due to the extra overhead to preprocess a Cypher query that has not been seen recently):

```
WITH '
  MATCH (a:Article)
  WHERE a.appearsInJournal = "Journal of Science"
  RETURN a.title, a.publicationDate
' AS query
UNWIND RANGE(1, 5) AS i
WITH i, query, datetime.realtime().epochMillis AS start
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(query, NULL) YIELD value
WITH i, MAX(datetime.realtime().epochMillis-start) AS execTime
SKIP 1
RETURN AVG(execTime)
```

This approach also includes the time to execute the `apoc.cypher.doIt` procedure as well, but that overhead seems to be under a millisecond. Also, this approach only seems to work if `query` returns non-NULL results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm trying to do this code with another query:  MATCH (a:authors)-[:`consists_of`]->(b:affiliation{id:'20455151'})
    RETURN a,b  and it says: Invalid input '20455151'  But separately from this code this query works

Comment: Since `query` is bounded by single quotes, all string literals inside the query have to use double quotes.

Comment: It works! Thank you :) Can you please tell me how can I also return execution time of each query. I tried RETURN execTime, but it doesn't work

Comment: You can use `RETURN AVG(execTime) AS average, COLLECT(execTime) AS times`

Comment: COLLECT(execTime) AS times. Shouldn't this code output only 4 values? I execute query 4 times. This code returns too many values. I slightly don't understand(

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle timing queries that return multiple rows. It now uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) `MAX` to get the time it takes to receive the *last row* for each `i`.

Comment: Still don't understand why sometimes it returns 4 values and sometimes 5 values. Can you please explain?)

Comment: Looks like I forgot to update my answer to my actual latest code. I have now done so. You should only get a single result.